# Weird behavior while using replaceWith() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some trouble in using jQuery. I'm trying to do an AJAX request and change the clicked element if that request gives the correct response.

My jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-to-check', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (response) {
            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            if (result.status == 'success') {
                $(e.target).replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>');
            } else if (result.status == 'failure') {
                // failure
            }
        },
    });
    return false;
});
```

My HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-left add-to-check" href="/tasks/check/1235"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
```

This doesn't properly work however. When I click the button, most of the times the button disappears as it should and a check icon shows up. This is the way it should be working.

Sometimes, however: The check mark shows up but it is still a button. And I cannot figure out why this is.

Comment: @RienNeVaPlu͢s Replacing it with $(this) was my initial thought. However, the script doesn't work when I do that. I think that's because I'm using $(document). Can someone back me up on this?

Comment: no it will not work because the context of `this` has changed.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but when you click the <i></i> element - isn't the target the actual <i> element? Therefore when you replace it, the link <a> element will remain, because the script replaced the <i> element which was the original target.

Comment: @koressak Interesting, what you mean to say is that if I click the button  without touching the icon, it targets the button. If I click the icon however, it will see the icon as target and therefore only replace the icon instead of the whole button? I will try to confirm this.

Comment: @Peter yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-to-check', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this);
var url = $this.attr('href');
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (response) {
        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        if (result.status == 'success') {
            $this.replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>');
        } else if (result.status == 'failure') {
            // failure
        }
    },
});
return false;
```

});

Comment: Using your solution the icon changes but the button stays a button. I would like the button to disappear.

Comment: Ah ok, then it should be `$this.replaceWith` instead of `$this.html`

Comment: Seems i've fixed the problem using `$this.closest('.add-to-check').replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>');`

Comment: Hm it should work without that, as $this already refers to the clicked object, .add-to-check

Answer (score 0):

Other approach is to have pre-generated and hidden the successful icon element (for example with class sucess).

When you get to the successful response from server (as the task has been completed) you just hide the link element and show the successful icon.